# Firefox CSS white-space:nowrap not being honoured

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a nav menu that has a dropdown, and in that dropdown there can be an indeterminate number of `<ul>` that need to sit left of each other and the parent li grow and shrink dependent on the number of `<ul>`.

This works fine in chrome but in Firefox the `<ul>` sit beneath each other, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a fiddle, to see the drop down hover over brand

http://jsfiddle.net/QUK8C/

Answer (score 3):

The li's are floated left, they are not affected by `white-space` you should use `display:inline-block` instead.

```
nav ul.dropdown > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue and haven't found any solution from web, but somehow managed to found fix myself. So, just position the element to `absolute` and  that will do the trick.

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <span style="position: absolute; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
        longtexthereuuurrrrrggghhhhhhh!!!
    </span>
</div>
```